# cocos2d sprite collision detection boundingbox

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection

I got 2 sprites. I use the boundingbox to check for collision with CGRectIntersectsRect. But it is not working.
HBBall and HBpaddle has a CCSprite called image.

Init:

```
    ball = [[HBBall alloc] init];
    ball.position = ccp(150, 50);
    [self addChild:ball];
    [update addObject:ball];

    paddle1 = [[HBPaddle alloc] init];
    paddle1.position = ccp(50, 160);
    [self addChild:paddle1];
```

Update:

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect([paddle1.image boundingBox], [ball.image boundingBox])) 
    CCLOG(@"ball hit paddle");
```

CGRectIntersectsRect retuns always true. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you cant pass directly the bounding box, because it's relative to the sprite. You MUST pass the absolute CGRect boundingbox like this:

```
s = CCsprite
s.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0);    
CGRect absoluteBox = CGRectMake(s.position.x, s.position.y, [s boundingBox].size.width, [s boundingBox].size.height);
```

make necessary adjustments!

hope can help!

Comment: A small point, but doesn't the s.position.x and s.position.y refer to the center of the sprite? 

To get the proper rect for the sprite, I think you should use:

CGRect absoluteBox = CGRectMake([s boundingBox].origin.x, [s boundingBox].origin.y, [s boundingBox].size.width, [s boundingBox].size.height);

HTH

Answer (score 0):

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-game-development/17082-cocos2d-collision-detection-between-sprites.html ? Have you googled? This seems like it would be a pretty basic issue in the cocos2d framework.