# How to detect the collision of three sprite in cocos2d-x 2.2?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x

I am new to cocos2d-x and I am implementing my own flappy bird.

Now I am working with the collision detection and I am stuck.

I added the down_pipe sprite and the up_pipe sprite to a parent sprite pipes, and I move the parent shift from right to left.

But when I check the collision by

```
if (bird->boundingBox().intersectsRect(pipes->boundingBox()))
```

It doesn't work.

And I try this way:

```
if (bird->boundingBox().intersectsRect(pipes->getChildByTag(DOWN_PIPE)->boundingBox()) || bird->boundingBox().intersectsRect(pipes->getChildByTag(UP_PIPE)->boundingBox()))
```

It still doesn't work.

How can I solve the problem? Any advice?

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/606/box2d-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-box2d-for-just-collision-detection-with-cocos2d-iphone

Comment: actually see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822077/cocos2d-sprite-collision-detection-boundingbox

Comment: @RachelGallen My problem is that I add two separate CCSprite to a parent CCSprite, then I cannot check the collision by what I've said above. And the size of boundingBox of the parent CCSprite is always {0.0,0.0} and the origin changes , and the boundingBox of the up_pipe and the down_pipe remain unchanged.

Comment: have you looked at `containsRect()`

Comment: Also, maybe you should use Box2D or Chipmunk for this?

Comment: size of boundingBox of the parent will be zero because it doesn't have a sprite to give it size.

Comment: try using convertToWorldSpace functions. Or use parent's position and size of down_pipe and up_pie to create a temporary rect. and check intersection with this.

Answer (score 2):

You try this,

```
        CCRect target = CCRectMake(pipes->getPosition().x - (pipes->getContentSize().width/2),pipes->getPosition().y - (pipes->getContentSize().height/2),pipes->getContentSize().width,pipes->getContentSize().height);
```

if (bird->boundingBox().intersectsRect(target))